# Use of undeclared type 'RoboViewController' Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I install RoboReaderPDF framework via pod in my project and I imported it in my `Bridging-Header.h` file

[image]

the issue is when I am trying to instantiate the `RoboViewController` I am getting this error

```
 Use of undeclared type 'RoboViewController'
```

[image]

any help!?

Comment: did you try a clean rebuild of your app?

Comment: yes I did that for many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your bridging header has not been set up correctly. It should have the following structure.

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#import <RoboReaderPDF/RoboReader.h>

#endif
```

Importing the `RoboReader.h` file will also import the view controller (check file contents).

Additionally, also check that your bridging header has been specified under  `Objective-C Bridging Header` key in `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` segment in Build settings.

Comment: bridging header is specified   Objective-C Bridging Header key in Swift Compiler - Code Generation segment in Build settings also I checked this before , I don't know what is the problem it is somehow strange for me

Comment: @MhmdBackerShehadi can you try importing some other objective C class via the bridging header and see if it works? then we can be sure if the problem lies in the bridging header setup or if it is library specific.